# Why is my Kia Rio making rapping sounds?

Tags: oil, stall, kia, rio

Oil and check engine lights were on so I changed theo oil. There was only about a quart that came out. Now the lights went out, but the engin raps and dies at stop lights and new oil is black.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!